# Ideal gas in quasistatic process

Tags: thermodynamics, statistical-mechanics

How to prove that ideal gas in quasistatic process where $x=x(V,T)$ is constant satisfy equation

$pV^f=const.$, where $f = (C_{x}-C_{p})/(C_{x}-C_{V})$

How to find $C_{x}$ for $p/V=const.$?

Comment: What is x supposed to represent?

Comment: Same question as Chet.

Comment: x represents the location, it is constant for quasistatic.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Given $x =x(V, T)$:
\begin{align}
dx =& \left(\frac{\partial x}{\partial V}\right)_T dV + \left(\frac{\partial x}{\partial T}\right)_V dT.\\
0 =& \left(\frac{\partial x}{\partial V}\right)_T dV + \left(\frac{\partial x}{\partial T}\right)_V dT, \tag{1}
\end{align}

for constant $x$. From the first law of thermodynamics: $\Delta Q = P dV + n C_V dT$
\begin{align}
\Delta Q =& P dV + n C_V dT.\,\,\text{Using Eq.(1) to replace }\, dV \,\text{ by } dT\\
\Delta Q =& \left\{ - P\left(\frac{\partial x}{\partial T}\right)_V / \left(\frac{\partial x}{\partial V}\right)_T + n C_V \right\} dT\\
n C_x =& \frac{\Delta Q}{dT}\Big\vert_x =\left\{ - P\left(\frac{\partial x}{\partial T}\right)_V / \left(\frac{\partial x}{\partial V}\right)_T + n C_V \right\} \tag{2}
\end{align}

Now using ideal gas equation $PV= nRT$ to replace $dT$ with $dP$ and $dV$ in Eq.(1), then carry the integration.
$$
  P dV + V dP = nR dT. \tag{3}
$$

Plug eq.(3) in Eq.(1):
\begin{align}
0 =& \left(\frac{\partial x}{\partial V}\right)_T dV + \left(\frac{\partial x}{\partial T}\right)_V \frac{1}{nR} \left\{  P dV + V dP \right\}.\\
0 =&\left\{ \left( \frac{\partial x}{\partial V}\right)_T + \left(\frac{\partial x}{\partial T}\right)_V\frac{P}{nR} \right\} dV +\left\{ \left(\frac{\partial x}{\partial T}\right)_V  \frac{V}{nR}\right\}dP\\
0 =&\left\{ nR+ P\left(\frac{\partial x}{\partial T}\right)_V /\left(\frac{\partial x}{\partial V}\right)_T  \right\} \frac{dV}{V} +\left\{ P\left(\frac{\partial x}{\partial T}\right)_V/\left(\frac{\partial x}{\partial V}\right)_T  \right\}\frac{dP}{P}\\
0 =&\left\{ nR+ n C_V- n C_x  \right\} \frac{dV}{V} +\left\{ n C_V- n C_x \right\}\frac{dP}{P}\\
\end{align}

In the last equation, we plug in the $C_x$ in Eq.(2). Recall that $R = C_p - C_x$, we then have:
\begin{align}
0 =&\left\{ nC_P - n C_x  \right\} \frac{dV}{V} +\left\{ n C_V- n C_x \right\}\frac{dP}{P}
\end{align}
The integration of this equation render your solution.